# Open model box when click link in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, model, popup

I am here new member , I want make a model box, I don't what's it's called which image is below: I want when anyone hit in link them my model will appear or open in an animated method. So as stackoverflow policy I created my code and try to make function where if user click link it open, I could do this. Becouse I am not familiar of jquery or JavaScript.

I hopes any wanna help mr and take me out of this trouble.

Overall my question is how I make if user click `<a href="#">Open Model</a>` then model open.

**Special Request** *Due to have I not much reputation,[I am new] I can't send image direct in this post my project model image in footer of this post. Also please do not mark me as in hold bcz I already reads many post related this but it was not helpful I am in scared How I add this.please help.*

My code is below:

```css
#colorbox {
 width:700px!important; height:600px!important;
}
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#fff;}
#colorbox{}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -50px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -75px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px -25px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y -25px 0;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:20px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#999;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:100px; color:#999;}
        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:42px; color:#444;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; color:#444;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:63px; color:#444;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#fff url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/loading.gif) no-repeat 5px 5px;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; display:block; color:#444;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to or needed in IE9.
  See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}

/*
  The following provides PNG transparency support for IE6
  Feel free to remove this and the /ie6/ directory if you have dropped IE6 support.
*/
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleRight.png);}

.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight {
    _behavior: expression(this.src = this.src ? this.src : this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.split('"')[1], this.style.background = "none", this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" + this.src + ", sizingMethod='scale')");
}
```

```html
<div id="cboxOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; display: block;">
</div>

<div id="colorbox" class="" autocomplete="off" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 50px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 375px; position: absolute; width: 550px; height: 306px; opacity: 1; cursor: auto; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="cboxWrapper" autocomplete="off" style="height: 356px; width: 600px;">

<div>
    <div id="cboxTopLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">    </div>
    <div id="cboxTopCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;">
    </div>
    <div id="cboxTopRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">     </div>
</div>

    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;">
      </div>
    <div id="cboxContent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px; height: 306px;">
    <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 550px; overflow: auto; height: 286px;">
    <div id="inline_content" style="background: #fff;" autocomplete="off">
    
  <h3 class="page-title_fg">Forget Password</h3>
    
  <form style="padding: 15px;">
   <label>User Name*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="fuserName" name="fuserName" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <label>Date of Birth*</label> <input type="text" id="fdob" name="fdob" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="clkdate('fdob');" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"><br> 
   <label>Email id*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="femailId" name="femailId" class="box" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <!-- <input type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" class="login_btn"/>
   <input type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" class="login_btn"/> -->
   <button type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" autocomplete="off">Get Password</button>
   
      <button type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" autocomplete="off">Reset</button>
  </form>
    
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxTitle" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: block;">     </div>
  
  <div id="cboxCurrent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxNext" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxPrevious" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  <div id="cboxSlideshow" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxClose" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">close
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxMiddleRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear: left;">
  
  <div id="cboxBottomLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxBottomCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxBottomRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <span id="calBorder" style="position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 137px; width: 208px; border: 1pt solid rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; cursor: move; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 10000; visibility: hidden;"></span>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMc7E.jpg

Comment: As I can see, do you want to make your own modal ? or did you check this simple way of creating a modal  - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 1):

Small sample with your code. But suggest you to follow @WC2 answer and modify your code accordingly since your code is little bit messy.

```js
$('#modal-open').click(function(){
    $('#modal-box').fadeIn('slow');
})


$('#cboxOverlay, #cboxClose').click(function(){
   $('#modal-box').fadeOut('slow');

})
```

```css
#colorbox {
 width:700px!important; height:600px!important;
}
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#fff;}
#colorbox{}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -50px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -75px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px -25px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y -25px 0;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:20px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#999;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:100px; color:#999;}
        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:42px; color:#444;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; color:#444;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:63px; color:#444;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#fff url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/loading.gif) no-repeat 5px 5px;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; display:block; color:#444;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to or needed in IE9.
  See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}

/*
  The following provides PNG transparency support for IE6
  Feel free to remove this and the /ie6/ directory if you have dropped IE6 support.
*/
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderTopRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomCenter.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderBottomRight.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleLeft.png);}
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight{background:url(images/ie6/borderMiddleRight.png);}

.cboxIE6 #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE6 #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE6 #cboxMiddleRight {
    _behavior: expression(this.src = this.src ? this.src : this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.split('"')[1], this.style.background = "none", this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" + this.src + ", sizingMethod='scale')");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal-box" style="display:none">

<div id="cboxOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; display: block;">  </div>


<div id="colorbox" class="" autocomplete="off" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 50px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 375px; position: absolute; width: 550px; height: 306px; opacity: 1; cursor: auto; overflow: hidden;">

<div id="cboxWrapper" autocomplete="off" style="height: 356px; width: 600px;">

<div>
    <div id="cboxTopLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">    </div>
    <div id="cboxTopCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;">
    </div>
    <div id="cboxTopRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">     </div>
</div>

    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;">
      </div>
    <div id="cboxContent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px; height: 306px;">
    <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 550px; overflow: auto; height: 286px;">
    <div id="inline_content" style="background: #fff;" autocomplete="off">
    
  <h3 class="page-title_fg">Forget Password</h3>
    
  <form style="padding: 15px;">
   <label>User Name*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="fuserName" name="fuserName" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <label>Date of Birth*</label> <input type="text" id="fdob" name="fdob" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="clkdate('fdob');" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"><br> 
   <label>Email id*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="femailId" name="femailId" class="box" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <!-- <input type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" class="login_btn"/>
   <input type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" class="login_btn"/> -->
   <button type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" autocomplete="off">Get Password</button>
   
      <button type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" autocomplete="off">Reset</button>
  </form>
    
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxTitle" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: block;">     </div>
  
  <div id="cboxCurrent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxNext" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxPrevious" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  <div id="cboxSlideshow" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxClose" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">close
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxMiddleRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear: left;">
  
  <div id="cboxBottomLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxBottomCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="cboxBottomRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;">
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <span id="calBorder" style="position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 137px; width: 208px; border: 1pt solid rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; cursor: move; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 10000; visibility: hidden;"></span>
  

  </div>
  
  <a id="modal-open">Open modal</a>
```

Comment: It is looks like sliding. Will check. And for close button get the class or id of that button and, write code to click event of it. as I wrote for others.

Comment: edited for close button

Comment: Why you not understand and ignore my question about to add animation effect when model open animated method like this [page] (easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy) >> Click `Forgot Password`  button and see the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#trigger-modal').click(function(){
    $('#screen, #modal').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#screen, #modal button').click(function(){
    $('#screen, #modal').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
#screen, #modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
}

#screen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    z-index: 1;
}

#modal {
    width: 33.333%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 33.3333%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen"></div>
<div id="modal">
    <p>Hello I'm a Modal</p>
    <button>x</button>
</div>
<p>Hi Me @ background</p>
<button id="trigger-modal">open modal</button>
```

Simple one : replace ur login div code with HTML code.

Comment: This like code presents on stackoverflow and codepen. But I have problem in my code.